# Getting GKE Deployment Information Via Go

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We have multiple GKE clusters in different GCP projects.

For each cluster in each project, I essentially want to run the following via Go:

```
kubectl get deployment [deployment_name] -o json | jq '.metadata.labels'
```

I already have 2 functions to get the GCP projects and the cluster names per project, the last of which uses:

```
"cloud.google.com/go/container/apiv1"
"google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/container/v1"
```

Is it possible to use these APIs to get the deployment information for the GKE clusters?
Or would I need to use *kubernetes/client-go*?

I couldn't seem to find a function that suited my needs under: https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/reference/cloud.google.com/go/container/latest/apiv1

And the kubernetes Go client seems to rely on a .kubeconfig file, whereas I'd just like to use $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, if possible:
https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration/main.go

Any help with this would be most appreciated.

Comment: I think my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73091940/609290) may help. You can use the Container library to get sufficient inforrmation to make an authenticated call to the cluster but you're going to need to use a Kubernetes SDK to effect `kubectl get deployment` in code.

Comment: Thanks, @DazWilkin - that certainly helped in getting authenticated to the clusters. I'll have to investigate how to get a list of deployments and their associated labels separately. One step at a time... :) Thanks again!